# UFT - How to get Cell Type or Value in Webtable

Tags: qtp, hp-uft

I need to get the cell type or value property in a Webtable by specifying the row and column. 
GetROproperty can give the value but row/column cannot be specified.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please be sure to provide enough context and samples with your questions. Feel free to check out https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask to help improve your question and increase the likelihood of a good answer.

Answer (score 1):

When working with a [`WebTable`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/15.0/UFT_Help/Subsystems/OMRHelp/OMRHelp.htm#Web/WEBPACKAGELib~WebTable.html) there are two ways to get into the cell:

- [`ChildItem`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/15.0/UFT_Help/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/Web/WEBPACKAGELib~WebTable.html#ChildItem): Allows you to specify a row and column of the cell and an object type so you can get an (for example) `Link` that is in the specified cell. Then with that `Link` object in hand you can do whatever you want, including `GetROProperty`
- [`Cell`](https://admhelp.microfocus.com/uft/en/15.0/UFT_Help/Subsystems/OMRHelp/Content/Web/WEBPACKAGELib~WebTable.html#Cell): Given a row and column, this returns the `WebElement` of the `TD` element that represents the cell which you can then use as a regular `WebElement`

Comment: Btw, do you know if the Cell method has been there all the time, or has it been added in 14.xx?

Comment: @TheBlastOne it wasn't always there, I don't remember exactly when it was added, either 12.54 or 14.